# Getting a New Access Token for NiFi REST API

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working with the NiFi REST API and have run into an issue with obtaining access tokens.

If I issue a request to the /access/token endpoint, I get an access token back in the response. If I then send another request to the same endpoint, I get a 403 forbidden response. I have tried this in all three environments that I have access to and all behave the same way.

I can send a request to the endpoint to the /access/token/expiration endpoint to see when the token expires.

Most access token endpoints that I have used for APIs simply return a new access token on subsequent requests. That doesn't seem to be the case with NiFi. Do I have to wait until the first token expires (looks to be about eight hours if I did the math correctly) in order to get a new one? Is there a way to invalidate the current token in order to get a new one much quicker if so? The issue is for the environment where I have done most of my work I saw the token but did not record it and would really not like to have to wait around for it to expire, now and in future scenarios.